# Best resources for project based learning?

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapps

I've been told about Crypto Zombies and one Discord group (https://discord.gg/MffMqPF3) as one of the best places to learn Solidity by building projects. Are there any other websites that you can recommend?

Comment: While the question is interresting, it is opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

Austin Griffith has put together a really good source :

ETH-Scaffold : https://github.com/austintgriffith/scaffold-eth
(Check out the various branches in this repo, each branch is a learning project)

buidlguidl : https://buidlguidl.com

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum.org has some great options.

Here is a link: https://ethereum.org/en/developers/learning-tools/